# JavaScript: how to pass additional information to source page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, hyperlink

I have a website and when a user follows an internal link I would like to pass some extra information to a new page, so JavaScript on the destination page could do some useful highlighting.

There is an option to pass that information via the link parameters (GET), but it will generate lots of virtually duplicate pages and break pretty URLs concept. Another way is to make a webapp using AJAX, but it will also bound content to a single URL.

How can I transparently pass some information to the new page during navigation w/o messing with site's URL structure?

Comment: POST request... but if the user ever goes to that page again (via get request with bookmarked url), it will not have the data...

Comment: Are both pages on same domain?

Comment: @epascarello That's is OK. The point is that the data is kind of temporary. There is no need to persist it between visits.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, the are on the same domain.

Comment: Use `sessionStorage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a few options.

**Form Submission**

First option post a form with the data. Add a hidden form, on the anchor click capture the click event, set the hidden fields with the values you want to send to the next page, and submit the form. On the next page, read the post parameters in the backend and update the page.

**Local Storage**

On click of the anchor, set localStorage to the values you want to appear on the next page. When the next page loads, read the localStorage values and update the page. Note: The server will not have access to the values

**Ajax with pushState**

Use Ajax to submit the form. When the Ajax call returns, use `window.history.pushState` to update the url with whatever url you want to be displayed to the user.

Comment: That's definetelly all of the options that I have explored so far. Picked **sessionStorage** for the time.

Answer (score 3):

You could store the data in local storage or session storage, and retrieve it again on the destination page.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options not mentioned is to create a *dirty* URL:

> /destination/**param1**/**value1**/...

then strip additional parameters at server-side and redirect:

> /destination

keeping additional values stored at server-side (e.g. via sessions). I still prefer using *sessionStorage* in a real application, but it worth mentioning anyway.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean it will "bind content to a single url"? AJAX request is the first thing that comes to my mind as the solution to this problem. You dont have to use the url of the page to make the ajax request, you can build the url inside your javascript based on whatever conditions exist in your application.

Besides AJAX and passing parameters in the URL, the only other thing I can think of is to use Cookies. That of course runs into problems if the user has cookies disabled. I think an Ajax call to your server is the most robust way of handling the problem.